# IAM rights to write in empty S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, bucket

I have the following
IAM rights:

```
"Effect":"Allow",
"Action":[
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:GetObject"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/folder/subfolder/*"
```

When I am writing the file `arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/folder/subfolder/file1.parquet` in the empty bucket for the very first time, are the folders and subfolders created automatically or do I have to create them in advance? In other words, are the IAM rights above sufficient to create the folders and subfolders (prefix) during the first writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not have the concept of directories. It is not a hierarchical file system, but an object storage. Every object has its own key where separators can be forward slash.

You don't need to create directories.

Comment: In fact, the api doesn't even require using `/` as the delimiter. You can pass an alternative. The console organizes using the slash, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Victor! But this means, that S3 only checks if the prefix of my file is equal to the prefix specified in the IAM. If this the case, then the writing is permitted. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct @justus. You could even write `arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/file2`, because the prefix would still match up to the wildcard.